# C# Inquiry (Reading from Text file)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I want to read a block of text from a text file that are separated by new line, but the number of lines in a block is inconsistent. And I think ReadLine method skips newline (correct me if I'm wrong).

Example of a text file:

```
asdlkf dfadfj adfasdf
asdfaf asdfjaslfk asdfjasldf
asdfajsdf

slfasdf
asdfasdf
adssdfas;
asdfasdfj

asdfasdf
asdfasdf
```

Comment: have you tried `File.ReadAllLines()`?

Comment: I have used File.ReadLines(). Does ReadAllLines() reads everyline in the text including a blank space (newline), because I need to determine where the block of text starts and ends, so I can store each block of text in to an array or some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming a block is a set of text seperated by an empty line.  I'm not fully clear based on your question.)

`File.ReadAllLines()` would work as well... but here is how you could do with with an iterator pattern.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetBlocks(string filename)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                if (sb.Length != 0)
                    yield return sb.ToString();
                sb.Clear();
            }
            else
                sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
        if (sb.Length != 0)
            yield return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

... usage ...

```
var blocks = GetBlocks("fortunes.txt");
```

... result ...

```
blocks = new [] {
    "asdlkf dfadfj adfasdf
     asdfaf asdfjaslfk asdfjasldf
     asdfajsdf",
    "slfasdf
     asdfasdf
     adssdfas;
     asdfasdfj",
    "asdfasdf
     asdfasdf",
};
```

Comment: Thanks you my good sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] s = File.ReadAllText(FileLocation).Replace("\r", "").Split('\n');

for(int i =0; i < s.Length; i++)
    MessageBox.Show(s[i]);//This will display each line in a message box.
```

This reads all text of a file then removes \r(This will stop you from getting stupid extra lines you don't need) and then .Split is splitting the \r into a array where the "enter" would be

Sorry for this example I'm not that good xD :P